# Rhino mocks and objects created in using statements

Tags: c#, mocking, rhino-mocks, using-statement

Most of the time when we use Rhino mocks it works well, but we have problems mocking objects created using the **using** statements.

We have a WCF proxy that is implemented as follows:

```
public class MyProxy : System.ServiceModel<IMyProxy>, IMyProxy
{
    public Response DoWork(Request request)
    {
         return base.Channel.DoWork(request);
    }
}
```

Normally in our business layer we would have a property:

```
 IProxy MyProxy;
```

Which we could set as being the mocked interface.

But when we use a using statement, our business layer looks like this:

```
using (MyProxy proxy = new MyProxy())
{
}
```

Which instanciates the concrete implementation of the class.

How do we get the business layer to use the mock created with Rhino mocks?

**Edit**

It turned out that you should not use using statements with wcf proxies http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inject `Func<IProxy>` into your class, and store it in a field.

Your code then becomes

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly Func<IProxy> createProxy;

    public MyClass(Func<IProxy> createProxy)
    {
        if (createProxy == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("createProxy");
        this.createProxy = createProxy;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        using (IProxy proxy = this.createProxy())
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Your unit test then looks like this:

```
[Test]
void MyClass_does_something()
{
    var proxyStub = MockRepository.CreateStub<IProxy>();
    var myClass = new MyClass(delegate { return proxyStub; });

    myClass.DoSomething();

    // make assertions...
}
```

Note that there [more relationships](http://nblumhardt.com/2010/01/the-relationship-zoo/) other than simple "A needs B" and "A creates B".

I have assumed that `IProxy` derives from `IDisposable` here. This is a bit of a simplification: the proxy instance may also have disposable dependencies of its own created by the container. You can't always just assume that those dependencies need to be disposed at the same time as the requested object. That's why it is better to use `Owned<T>` as illustrated in the blog post I linked above.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that it's the `using` statement that's the problem here - I expect it's the fact that it's using a constructor.

One way round this is to use dependency injection to give the object a *provider* (aka factory) for the object in question. In tests, you can then give it a provider which returns your mock object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have updated the question, hopefully it is a bit clearer. Wondering if the answer is that we cannot use Rhino mocks for this.

Comment: @Shiraz: I don't see how your update invalidates my answer in any way. Instead of calling a constructor, you ask the factory for a new `IMyProxy`. That way, you can have a factory which returns Rhino Mock ones instead.

Answer (score 2):

I would change the code to use an IoC system, to look more like:

```
using (IMyProxy proxy = IoC.Resolve<IMyProxy>())
{
}
```

With `IMyProxy` inheriting `IDisposable`.
Then in the test environment, set up the IoC to return the mock instead of the runtime type.

Comment: ack, [service locator anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx)!

Comment: I'm afraid it'll take more than one man's blog entry to convince me it's an anti-pattern.  It has pros and cons but for the the pros outweigh the cons.